# I cannot override a specifity to change the color of an el in my navBar

Tags: css

I cannot seem to override a specifity, would you please help me figure it out?

I even tried to use !important as a desperate move which did't work...

Conclusion, I am missing something fundamental and my old friend google isn't helping much.

The element targeted in the full code below is :

```
<li id="mid-el"><a id="mid-a" href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

The color of all elements is set to white.
The targeted el needs to be : rgb(25,2,80) :

```
nav.nav-bar ul.group-one li.mid-el a#mid-a {
  color: rgb(25,2,80);
}
```

A detailed explaination would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav.nav-bar {
  background-color: rgb(25, 2, 80);
  padding: 25px;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

li, a {
  margin-top: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li:nth-child(6) {
  margin: 0px 120px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

nav.nav-bar ul.group-one li#mid-el a {
  color: rgb(25,2,80);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <ul class="group-one">
        <li><a href="/">
          <div>
            <img class="logo-img" src="#" alt="Logo-B&D">
          </div>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Groupe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Expertise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Référence</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Actualités</a></li>
        <li id="mid-el"><a id="mid-a" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="right-group"><a href="#">Rejoignez-nous</a></li>
        <li class="right-group"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="right-group"><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
        <li class="right-group"><a href="#">
          <div class="sm-icon">
            <img src="" class="t-icon" alt="Twitter">
            <img src="" class="i-icon" alt="Insta">
            <img src="" class="f-icon" alt="Facebook">
            <img src="" class="y-icon" alt="Youtube">
          </div>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Whats the question? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **CSS:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: rgb(25, 2, 80);
  padding: 25px;
}

.group-one {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  margin-top: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li:nth-child(6) {
  margin: 0px 120px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

.group-one #mid-el a {
  color: rgb(25, 2, 80);
}
```

Also **HTML** has some ending tags problems

```html
    <nav className="nav-bar">
      <ul className="group-one">
        <li>
          <a href="/">
            <div>
              <img className="logo-img" src="#" alt="Logo-B&D" />
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Groupe</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Expertise</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Référence</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Actualités</a>
        </li>
        <li id="mid-el">
          <a id="mid-a" href="#">
            Contact
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="right-group">
          <a href="#">Rejoignez-nous</a>
        </li>
        <li className="right-group">
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li className="right-group">
          <a href="#">Finance</a>
        </li>
        <li className="right-group">
          <a href="#">
            <div className="sm-icon">
              <img src="" className="t-icon" alt="Twitter" />
              <img src="" className="i-icon" alt="Insta" />
              <img src="" className="f-icon" alt="Facebook" />
              <img src="" className="y-icon" alt="Youtube" />
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

you are not using CSS selectors right, if are using a class name in a selector than dont use the tag name with it like you wrote: `nav.nav-bar`  and `nav.nav-bar ul.group-one li.mid-el a` plus you gave your `<li>` tag an id not a class so id in css selector is used by a `#` not a `.` thus, the css selector should be written as `.group-one #mid-el a`

Comment: take a look at some basic selectors of CSS https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer and all clarifications. <br />

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your selector `nav.nav-bar ul.group-one li.mid-el a#mid-a {}`.

Specifically there is no `li` element with a class of "mid-el". Instead it has an ID of "mid-el". Simply change the period in the selector to a #.

`nav.nav-bar ul.group-one li#mid-el a#mid-a {color: rgb(25,2,80); }`